# Is there a command line tool for managing packages written by me?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, make, github, gitlab

Lately I've found myself writing small programs that I use across multiple machines. I use `gitlab` to manage these programs. Is there a command line tool that will help me keep my programs up-to-date?

If this question is too general or too vague, then I can post a simple example to illustrate what I'm interested in.

Comment: What languages is your s/w written in? Python?

Comment: Please extend the question with examples. On what platforms do you run these applications is also required to recommend a distribution method, and the programming scripting language as stated in the comment above is also needed to know if you will be compiling or just running.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest taking a look at [`fpm` - effing package manager is the name](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) or the [docs here](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm). You can use `fpm` to convert anything to a package, such as RPM, DEB, etc. Pretty solid tutorial here - [How To Use FPM To Easily Create Packages in Multiple Formats](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-fpm-to-easily-create-packages-in-multiple-formats).

Using `fpm` you can take builds of your software and generate .deb or .rpm files like this:

```
$ cd dir_with_my_app_built
$ fpm -s dir -t rpm -C /tmp/project --name project_name \
    --version 1.0.0 --iteration 1 --depends  redhat_dependency1 \
    --description "A sample package" .
```

Results in this: `project_name-1.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm`.